# How can I get a function entry point?

Tags: c

I created a child process from within my process with CreateProcess() and suspend the child process. I can get the main entry point in the memory of child process, but how should I get function entry point of child process?

This is how I get the main entry point of child process

```
DWORD FindEntryPointAddress( TCHAR *exeFile )
{
  BY_HANDLE_FILE_INFORMATION bhfi;
  HANDLE hMapping;
  char *lpBase;

  HANDLE hFile = CreateFile(exeFile, GENERIC_READ, FILE_SHARE_READ, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);

  if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    ;

  if (!GetFileInformationByHandle(hFile, &bhfi))
    ;

  hMapping = CreateFileMapping(hFile, NULL, PAGE_READONLY, bhfi.nFileSizeHigh, bhfi.nFileSizeLow, NULL);

  if (!hMapping)
    ;

  lpBase = (char *)MapViewOfFile(hMapping, FILE_MAP_READ, 0, 0, bhfi.nFileSizeLow);

  if (!lpBase)
    ;

  PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER dosHeader = (PIMAGE_DOS_HEADER)lpBase;

  if (dosHeader->e_magic != IMAGE_DOS_SIGNATURE)
    ;

  PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32 ntHeader = (PIMAGE_NT_HEADERS32)(lpBase + dosHeader->e_lfanew);

  if (ntHeader->Signature != IMAGE_NT_SIGNATURE)
    ;

  DWORD pEntryPoint = ntHeader->OptionalHeader.ImageBase + ntHeader->OptionalHeader.AddressOfEntryPoint;

  UnmapViewOfFile((LPCVOID)lpBase);

  CloseHandle(hMapping);

  CloseHandle(hFile);

  printf( "test.exe entry point: %p\n", pEntryPoint );

  return pEntryPoint;
} // FindEntryPointAddress()
```

My purpose is if I don't have the child process source code and I just have the child process .exe file, can I get the function entry point of child process?

child process like this

```
void foo()
{
  char str[10];
  strcpy( str, "buffer\n" );
} // foo()

int main()
{
  foo();
  return 0;
} // main()
```

Comment: I've never heard of an entrypoint for a function, as far as I know, `main` itself is the entrypoint of the program. If there is such a thing, I would be really glad to know!

Comment: If it's not in the same source file as `main`, then it might be in another source file compiled together with the main source file. Or it's in a library in which case you need to look up the library.

Comment: You mean `&foo`, which is equivalent to just `foo`?

Comment: Welcome to SO. It seems to me that we have a problem of vocabulary with your question. Could you please describe in more detail what you are trying to achieve? I think you should be able to "edit" your question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing called an `entry point` for a function. If you want to understand the flow of execution when a function is called, then you can put some `printf()` statements like as follows:

```
#include <stdio.h>

void foo(void)
{
    printf("Entering %s:%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
    return;
}

int main(void)
{  
    printf("Entering %s:%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__);
    foo();
    return 0;
}
```

Or you can use [`gdb`](http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) and set `breakpoints` in the beginning of each function to see the flow of execution!

Answer (score 0):

Using `gdb` and `breakpoints` as suggested by Sangeeth Saravanaraj is actually the best method, but if you're intent on a runtime solution and would like an alternative to continually copy and pasting the same `printf` statement in every function you would like to track, you can use a *(possibly dangerous)* macro.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define trace_func(_func) printf("Entering %s:%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__); _func

void fooAgain(int myValue)
{
    printf("This is fooAgain, with my value: %d.\n", myValue);
}

void foo(void)
{
    printf("Hello, I'm foo.\n");
    trace_func(fooAgain(15));
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    trace_func(foo());
    return 0;
}
```

Returns:

```
Entering *yourfilepath*/main.c:main:18
Hello, I'm foo.
Entering *yourfilepath*/main.c:foo:13
This is fooAgain, with my value: 15
```

If you want to be a terrible person and be able to leave the code in even when you build for release, you can do this (but don't, it is a horrible practice and wrong. I include it for the sake of completion).

Change the define statements to:

```
#define TRACE_FUNCTIONS

#ifdef TRACE_FUNCTIONS
    #define trace_func(_func) printf("Entering %s:%s:%d\n", __FILE__, __func__, __LINE__); _func
#else
    #define trace_func(_func) _func
#endif
```

Comment: Sorry I had not explain clearly.

If I have a process A and I use API `CreateProcess()` to create and suspend

process B, I can find the main function entry point from memory space of B, but how should I 

find the entry point of function foo()?